# How do I make a while loop with multiple conditions stop at a true condition?

Tags: bash

I am supplying a while loop with the following

```
#!/bin/bash
number1=1
while [ -z "$number2" ] | [ "$number2" == 404 ] & [ "$number2" != 200 ] & [ "$number1" -lt 13 ]; do
  #number2=$(some command which can actually get a number)
  number2=200 # <<< e.g. a command that would return 
  let number1=number1+1
done
```

### This is what I need to do

> If `number2` is null do the loop
>   If `number2` is 404 do the loop
>   If `number2` is 200 don't do the loop
>   Do the loop until `number1` is 12

When I try the loop with `number2=200` it doesn't stop. It seems I am having a challenge with having it to stop where `number2` is `200`.

How do I write the statement such that it will stop the while loop when `number2=200` or is there an alternative?

Comment: What would happen if `$number2` is 300 or 500?

Comment: @Kusalananda `$number2` is either null 404 or 200

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If number2 is null do the loop
>   If number2 is 404 do the loop
>   If number2 is 200 don't do the loop
>   Do the loop until number1 is 12

In other words, repeat as long as `(number2 is null OR number2 = 404) AND (number2 != 200) AND (number1 <= 12)`. Note that you need some sort of grouping here, to make the precedence of AND and OR explicit. (In Bash, `&&` and `||` operate from left to right, but often the AND-operator binds more strongly than an OR-operator.)

Though you didn't say what should happen for other values of `number2`, so we might as well drop the first two conditions, since if `number2` is null or 404, then it can't be 200. So we get `(number2 != 200) AND (number1 <= 12)`.

Here,

```
while [ -z "$number2" ] | [ "$number2" == 404 ] & [ "$number2" != 200 ] & [ "$number1" -lt 13 ]; do ...
```

you have `|` and `&` instead of `||` and `&&`. `|` indicates a pipeline, and `&` runs the preceding command in the background. So the above would run three commands in parallel: one pipeline with two tests, and another with one test, both in the background; and one test in the foreground. That doesn't make much sense. I mentioned `&&` and `||` above, those are the logical condition operators in Bash.

The simplified form would be:

```
while [ "$number2" != 200 ] && [ "$number1" -le 12 ]; do ...
```

(You may also want to use somewhat more descriptive variable names than "number1" and "number2".)

Comment: Thanks.. let me go through the commands and see if i need more clarity

Answer (score 7):

Logical operators in the shell are `&&` and `||`.  The `&` and `|` does *very* different things (starts a background task and sets up a pipe between two processes, respectively).

---

```
#!/bin/sh

number1=1

while [ "$number1" -le 12 ]; do

    number2=$( some command )

    case $number2 in
        200)
            break
            ;;
        ""|404)
            # nothing
            ;;
        *)
            printf 'Unexpected: number2 = %s\n' "$number2" >&2
            exit 1
    esac

    number1=$(( number1 + 1 ))

done
```

The number in `$number2` looks like a HTTP status code.  Testing the value in a `case` statement as above would allow you to select the correct action given any number of status codes without making the shell code an unwieldy mess of `if`-statements.  For example, the action for *any* client or server failure code could be triggered by the pattern `4??|5??`.

This also logically separates the semantics of the two variables.  The `number1` variable controls the number of iterations, while `number2` is strictly for  controlling the action to take based on the outcome of your mystery command.

Comment: ya the mystery command returns HTTP code and I want to do recheck if with another number if I get 404 again and stop if I get 200 and do something after

Comment: @BretJoseph In that case, you may want to do an additional check after the loop to make sure that you know _why_ the loop terminated.  It can terminate because of having run 12 times, or it may terminate because you got your 200 status.

Comment: as long as it stops after the 200 status or re-loops if not its fine, I will make it do something before it breaks